# Are there Esperanto variants in ISO 639 codes?

Tags: language

The ISO 639 code that I know for Esperanto is `eo`. As far as I know, and according to [RFC 3066](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html) there are no recognized distinct variant.

For example French have many variants: `fr-AD`, `fr-BE`, `fr-BF`, `fr-BI`, `fr-BJ`, `fr-CA`, `fr-CD`, `fr-CF`, `fr-CG`, `fr-CH`, `fr-CI`, `fr-CM`, `fr-DJ`, `fr-FR`, `fr-GA`, `fr-GB`, `fr-GF`, `fr-GN`, `fr-GP`, `fr-HT`, `fr-IT`, `fr-KM`, `fr-LB`, `fr-LU`, `fr-MC`, `fr-MG`, `fr-ML`, `fr-MQ`, `fr-NC`, `fr-NE`, `fr-PF`, `fr-PM`, `fr-RE`, `fr-RW`, `fr-SC`, `fr-TD`, `fr-TG`, `fr-VU`, `fr-WF`, `fr-YT`.

So can I indeed conclude that there is no official `eo-..` code out there?

Comment: As there are no distinct variants of Esperanto I would assume that you are correct in concluding that there are no distinct ISO code variants either.

Comment: There are ways of making the Esperanto characters.  Kern punkto has an interesting discussion of it here: https://kern.punkto.info/2016/11/24/kp100-unikodo/ .  In Esperanto, klare...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IETF RFC 3066](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3066.txt) is obsolete. The current authoritative reference for language tags is [**IETF BCP 47**: Tags for Identifying Languages](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47). The [document by Tex Texin and John Cowan](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html) that you reference is explicitly marked as a draft and was last updated in January 2005, four years before the publication of IETF BCP 47.

**IETF BCP 47** does not list the accepted ISO language tags but defines how to use language tags, e.g. the choice between an [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) two-letter code and an [ISO-639-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-3) three-letter code, and how to add country codes and/or script codes.

The list of ISO 639-1 language codes is maintained by [Infoterm in Austria](http://www.infoterm.info/standardization/iso_639_1_2002.php), list of ISO 639-3 language tags is [maintained by SIL](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/default.asp), while the list of ISO 3166 country codes is [maintained by the ISO 3166 Maintenance Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166#ISO_3166_Maintenance_Agency) in Geneva.

IANA maintains a [**subtag registry**](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) (defining, e.g. `eo-Latn` as the only Esperanto-related tag), but it is not clear who or what would give IANA the authority to prohibit tags that are not in their registry.

As far as I can see, you *can*, strictly speaking, create codes such as `eo-FR`, assuming that there is (in this case) a specific French variant of Esperanto, but what would be the use case for such a tag and which tools would support it?